# Inno Setup- make sure that directory is NOT readonly?

Tags: windows, installation, permissions, inno-setup

I have an Inno Setup installer which copies some files into `Program Files`, the `[Files]` section is set up like this:

```
[Files]
Source: "Bundled_Files\*"; DestDir: "{commonpf64}\StudioLinked\Romplur\"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Permissions: users-full;
```

The files copied from inside `Bundled_Files` always end up being set to read-only. I've set the permissions to `users-full` but that doesn't seem to change anything. Is there a way to ensure that files are made NOT read-only?

I tried adding an additional [Dirs] section before the [Files] section like so:

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{commonpf64}\StudioLinked\Romplur\"; Permissions: users-full;
```

But this also didn't change the read-only setting on the folders.

Using Inno Setup 6.2.1 on Windows 10. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code to make a subdirectory of my installation directory writable and editable:

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\MyWritableSubDir"; Permissions: users-modify
```

However, you should store only data files in any writable directory or sub-directory of "C:\Program Files", never executables: Otherwise this opens a security hole (there is a reason why "C:\Program Files" is read-only for normal users!).

The correct place to store application specific data, as intended by Microsoft, is either the ProgramData directory or the AppData directory. See [Where is the correct place to store my application specific data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563148/where-is-the-correct-place-to-store-my-application-specific-data) for a more general discussion.

See https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts how to use these directories in Inno Setup.